# Как обновить TextBox в UpdatePanel по мере изменения данных в функции сервера

Tags: c#, asp.net

подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть кусок страницы:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="137px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="398px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers> 
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1"/> 
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

На стороне сервера крутится функция с циклом, например такая:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + i.ToString() + "\n";
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
```

Как сделать так, чтоб на каждой итерации цикла обновлялось значение на стороне клиента. А так оно выводится все по окончанию цикла.
Пробовал TextBox1.DataBind(); UpdatePanel1.Update(); UpdatePanel1.DataBind(); - не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко - никак. ASP.NET WebForms работает через постбеки. Каждый раз, когда вы делаете что-то на клиенте, ASP.NET:

- посылает запрос на сервер
- создает там заново объект страницы
- выполняет обработчик
- рендерит результат (всю страницу или отдельные update panel)
- шлет результат на клиент и там обновляет соответствующие куски страницы

После того, как результат ушел на клиент, его никак с сервера поменять нельзя. Объекты страницы на сервере после этого - мусор, и все изменения в них просто ничего не делают.

Если вам нужно периодически что-то менять - дергайте постбэки с клиента, раз в секунду. Или переходите на нормальные новые технологии - ASP.NET MVC + SignalR вполне справятся с обновлением клиента по событиям с сервера.

ASP.NET WebForms безнадежно устарел, нет никакого смысла его учить.

Comment: А можете показать пример, как сделать постбэк. Я так понимаю это через ajax нужно.

Comment: @СергейФедотов принудительные постбэки можно делать через [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference?view=netframework-4.8), но в целом для динамики asp.net webforms плохо приспособлен. Если есть возможность перейти на mvc - переходите, даже не задумывайтесь